# Getting colored open circles to indicate the absense of a number in the domain of a function

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code instructs TikZ to plot a function and its derivative.  There are two modifications that I would like.  Since the function is not differentiable at 0, I would like to have open circles at the points (0, -1) and (0, -2), and since the graph of the derivative is yellow, I would like the circles to be yellow.  The "-1" on the y-axis is obscured by the graph of the derivative.  I have `fill=white` optional specification for the `ticklabel style` command, but it seems to be ignored.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5.25,xmax=5,
    domain=-5.25:5, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-6,ymax=6,
    restrict y to domain=-6:6,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},ytick={-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-5:0,blue] {-x)};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-5:0,yellow] {-1)};
\draw [fill=white, yellow] (0,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0:5,blue] {-2*x)} node[right,pos=0.9]{$\scriptstyle{y} = f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0:5,yellow] {-2)} node[right,pos=0.9]{$\scriptstyle{y} = f^{\prime}(x)$};
\draw [fill=white, yellow] (0,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yellow is a really really bad choice for line color.  You can get the open circles via

```
fill=none, draw=black
```

Using `draw=yellow` does draw the open circle but it is very difficult to see.

[image]

For the `-1` y tick label, I would recommend you leave that out. However, if you want the tick label to appear on top, the you need to use `layers`. Otherwise the tick labels are on a layer in the background and the `fill=` option won't have effect. So, adding the options

```
    set layers=axis on top,
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny, fill=white, circle, inner sep=0.5pt},
```

yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- For the circle, the `fill=none` option was used instead of `fill=white`. Using `fill=none` allows the line below to be visible. If you don't want that then you can use `fill=white`.
- I added `inner sep=0.5pt` so as to keep the spacing around the tick label to be a small amount. The default `inner sep` is `.3333em` which results in a rather large space around the tick label.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5.25,xmax=5,
    domain=-5.25:5, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-6,ymax=6,
    restrict y to domain=-6:6,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
    ytick={-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-5:0,blue, thick] {-x)};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-5:0,yellow, thick] {-1)};
\draw [fill=none, draw=black] (0,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0:5,blue, thick] {-2*x)} node[right,pos=0.9]{$\scriptstyle{y} = f(x)$};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0:5,yellow, thick] {-2)} node[right]{$\scriptstyle{y} = f^{\prime}(x)$};
\draw [fill=none, draw=black] (0,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the code!  It instructs TikZ to plot the graph that I wanted.  (I kept the "-1" on the y-axis.  I don't want it to feel picked on.)  I already had the command `ticklabel style={fill=white}` in my code.  Doesn't that tell TikZ to typeset the tick marks surrounded by some white space on the Cartesian plane?  Also, you have `\draw [fill=none, draw=black] (0,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt]` to draw the circles.  I was told to use the option `fill=white` to get the circle.

Comment: I did not use the optional specifications `circle, inner sep=0.5pt` in the command for tick marks.  Would I use this if I wanted a little more space about the tick mark?  What does `inner sep=0.5pt` specify?  Is it that the closest that a circle around -1 gets to -1 is 0.5pt?  What is the default inner separation?

Comment: Updated answer to explain your questions. Let me know if that is clearer. And play with the `inner sep` and see the results (might need to zoom in to see).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response.  I have not had time to look at the change in code.  I will look later and reply.  I appreciate the update!